# PSTricks: Wrong axis labels

Tags: pstricks, labels

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\sandsynlighed#1#2{%
  \psframe[
    linecolor = red,
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = blue!50
  ](#1,0)(!#1 \bredde add #2 4 div)
}

\psset{unit=0.75}

\begin{document}

\def\bredde{1.5 }
\begin{pspicture}(-0.9,-0.5)(14.3,11.3)
  % Akserne.
  \psaxes[
    xlabelOffset = -0.75,
    Ox = -1,
    dx = 1.5,
    xLabels = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6_{+0},6_{+1},7},
    Dy = 2,
    dy = 0.5
  ]{->}(0,0)(-0.25,-0.25)(14,10.75)[$X$,0][$100 \cdot P(X)$,90]
  % Sandsynlighederne.
  \sandsynlighed{0}{18.70}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As can be seen, the labels on the *x*-axis is all wrong and I have no idea what I have done wrong. I would like to have the labels as specified by `xLabels`; how do I get this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got conflicting directives going on for the x-axis.  Try something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\sandsynlighed#1#2{%
  \psframe[
    linecolor=red,
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=blue!50
  ](#1,0)(!#1 \bredde add #2 4 div)
}

\psset{unit=0.75}

\begin{document}

\def\bredde{1.5 }
\begin{pspicture}(-0.9,-0.5)(14.3,11.3)
  \psaxes[
    xlabelOffset=-0.75,
    %%Ox=-1,
    %%dx=1.5,
    xLabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6_{+0},6_{+1},7},
    Dy=2,
    dy=0.5
  ]{->}(14,10)[$X$,0][$100 \cdot P(X)$,90]
  % Sandsynlighederne.
 \sandsynlighed{0}{18.70}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Given your comment, here's a fairly different approach.  Here I delved into the `pst-plot` package to look at how labels are placed and copied some of the code.  The key here is the `\multido` macro.  Also, since the label positions are enumerated with `\nA`, but we're stepping by `2`, I added another counter `\nB` to extract the correct label from `\psk@xLabels`.  All this is wrapped up in the macro `\myxlabels`

To get the desired spacing, I set the `xunit` to a new value.  Perhaps you may not want to do this globally.  If so, then just reassign `xunit` within a group enclosing the `pspicture`.

Also, you don't need to add the extra space to `\bredde` as you did.  You can use `\space` in the call to the post-script commands.

Here's a new MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\sandsynlighed#1#2{%
  \psframe[
    linecolor=red,
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=blue!50
  ](#1,0)(!#1 \bredde\space add #2 4 div)
}

\makeatletter
\def\myxlabels#1{\def\psk@xLabels{#1}%%'
      \multido{\nA=1+2,\nB=0+1}{10}{\uput{\psxlabelsep}[-90]{\pst@xLabelsRot}(\nA,0)%%'
      {\strut\pshlabel{\psPutXLabel{\nB}}}}%%'
}
\makeatother

\psset{unit=0.75,xunit=0.75}

\begin{document}

\def\bredde{2}
\begin{pspicture}[](-0.9,-0.5)(14.3,11.3)
  \psaxes[
    dx=2,
    xLabels={,},
    Dy=2,
    dy=0.5
  ]{->}(20,10)[$X$,0][$100 \cdot P(X)$,90]
  %% Sandsynlighederne.
  \myxlabels{0,1,2,3,4,5,6_{+0},6_{+1},7}

 \sandsynlighed{0}{18.70}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like the unit on the x-axis to be 1.5, and the labels and tick marks to be at the horizontal center of the bars.

Comment: Super; thank you. If anyone (maybe @herbert ...) has a non-hack solution, please let me know. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

the offset was not working for special label setting. Try `pst-plot.tex` from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-plot/  Then use something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}    
\def\sandsynlighed#1#2{%
  \psframe[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,
           fillcolor=blue!50](#1,0)(!#1 \bredde add #2 4 div)}

\psset{unit=0.75}
\begin{document}

\def\bredde{1.5 }
\begin{pspicture}(-0.9,-0.5)(14.3,11.3)
  % Akserne.
  \psaxes[
    xunit=1.5,
    xLabels={,0,1,2,3,4,5,6_{+0},6_{+1},7},
    xlabelOffset=-0.75,
    Dy=4,dy=1,
  ]{->}(9,10.75)[$X$,0][$100 \cdot P(X)$,90]
  % Sandsynlighederne.
  \sandsynlighed{0}{18.70}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Herbert. Does this version of `pst-plot.tex` get to CTAN soon? If so, I'll just wait.

Comment: yes, next week, hopefully ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up with; besides from incorporating the improvements of the labels in `pst-plot`, it is also possible to scale both axes (the width of the x-axis by changing the value of `\xUnit` and the units on the y-axis by changing the value of `\yUnit`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfp}

\def\displacement{\fpeval{\xUnit/2}}
\def\yunit{\fpeval{\yUnit/4}}
\def\axisHeight{\fpeval{40/\yUnit+0.4}}
\def\width{\fpeval{9*\xUnit+0.8}}

\makeatother
\def\probability#1#2{%
  \psframe[
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = blue!50,
    linecolor = red
  ](\fpeval{#1*\xUnit},0)(\fpeval{(#1+1)*\xUnit},\fpeval{#2/4})%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\def\xUnit{1.1}
\def\yUnit{4}
\centering
 \psset{dimen = m}
  \begin{pspicture}(-1.3,-0.6)(\width,11.0)
    % Axes.
    \psaxes[
      xunit = \xUnit,
      xLabels = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6_{+0},6_{+1},7},
      xlabelOffset = -\displacement,
      yunit = \yunit,
      dy = 1,
      Dy = \yUnit
    ]{->}(0,0)(0,0)(9.3,\axisHeight)[$X$,0][$100 \cdot P(X)$~[\si{\percent}],90]
    % Probabilities.
    \probability{0}{18.70}
    \probability{1}{39.83}
    \probability{2}{29.87}
    \probability{3}{9.958}
    \probability{4}{1.532}
    \probability{5}{0.1021}
    \probability{6}{0.002432}
    \probability{7}{0.0001667}
    \probability{8}{0.000001198}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]